# ¿Como hacer una consulta 'SELECT' en MySQL de una tabla que probablemente exista?

Tags: mysql

Use estos codigos para ejecutar consultas en MySQL y funciona normal

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos_2018
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datos_2018
```

Pero no se como usar ese misco código para una consulta 'SELECT', intente usar de la siguiente manera, pero me dio error

```
SELECT * FROM IF EXISTS datos_2018
```

Comment: La tabla siempre debería existir. Estás planteando una solución incorrecta. Según veo lo que deberías tener es una tabla que también almacene una fecha.

Comment: Las tablas son parte lo que se llama modelo de datos de tu aplicación. ¿Acaso has diseñado una aplicación sin modelo de datos, al antojo de cualquiera? ¿Por qué no existen ya las tablas que deberían existir de antemano? Eso sería confundir una tabla con una fila de una tabla, que sí se puede crear dinámicamente.

Answer (score 2):

A menos que sólo quieras la cantidad de registros.

```
SELECT
IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (DATABASE()) AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'datos_2018')>0,
    (SELECT `TABLE_ROWS` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (DATABASE()) AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'datos_2018 '),
    'No existe'
)
```

Y la precisión de la cantidad de registros varía si usa INNODB u otros.

Dudo que se pueda de otra manera porque no veo la forma de recurrir a escribir algo diferente a `select * from <tabla inexistente>` lo cual eso, aunque no se ejecute en cierta condición, produce un error.

### Actualización: Es posible.

Utilizando la función `EXECUTE` es posible, de cierta forma, realizar lo que comentas.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_if_exist(tabla varchar(100))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME = tabla)
    THEN
        set @body = CONCAT('select * from ', tabla, ';');
        PREPARE stm FROM @body;
        EXECUTE stm;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'No existe';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Ya después de crear este procedimiento, se puede llamar de esta manera.

```
CALL select_if_exist('datos_2018');
```

Claramente todo esto es extremadamente peligroso y sólo lo puse contestando tu pregunta. El problema siempre vendrá de si el usuario del API puede acceder directamente hasta este proceder.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un consulta antes del select

```
SHOW tables like 'datos_2018';
```

Si la respuesta esta vacia entonces no existe y si la respuesta tiene una fila entonces si existe la tabla. Despues de esa consulta ya puedes realizar el `SELECT` con la seguridad que exista la tabla.

Comment: Pero como hago para que si en caso existiese la tabla me muestre todos los registros que hay en ella

Comment: @FreddyLimachiOrtega ¿eres consciente del riesgo de tu manera de proceder?  : *ˆ«Pero como hago para que si en caso existiese la tabla me muestre todos los registros que hay en ella»* ... Supongamos que un usuario mal intencionado escribe una tabla con datos sensibles, le estaría mostrando en pantalla datos como los nombres de usuarios administradores, las contraseñas, etc.

Comment: De acuerdo al lenguaje que utilizes puedes hacer la consulta en un try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM datos_2018), (SELECT * FROM datos_2018), 'NO EXISTE');
```

Comment: Eso no va a funcionar si no existe la tabla. Y, si existiera, sólo devuelve una columna, de caso contrario marcaría otro error.